# Did I prove and disprove the following statements correctly?

Tags: proof-writing

### Let $A = \left\{x \in \mathbb{Z} \mid \exists a\in\mathbb{Z}: x = 6a + 4\right\}$

### and $B = \left\{y \in \mathbb{Z} \mid \exists b\in\mathbb{Z}:  y = 18b - 2\right\}$

### and $C = \left\{z \in\mathbb{Z} \mid \exists c\in\mathbb{Z}:z = 18c + 16\right\}$

### Prove or disprove each of the following statements:

### a.  $A\subseteq B$

### b.  $B\subseteq A$

### c.  $A = B$

### Did I Prove these correctly?

a. A ⊆ B.
Suppose x is a particular, but arbitrarily chosen element of A.
By definition of A, there is an integer a, such that 6a+4.
Suppose that a = 1 then 6(1)+4=10=x.
Suppose y is a particular, but arbitrarily chosen element of B.
By definition of B, there is an integer b, such that 18b-2.
If x, or 10 in this case is an element of A, then it must be an element of B for A⊆B.
However if 18b-2=10 then 
18b=12
b=12/18
b=⅔
Therefore, b is not an integer thus 10 is an element of A, but not of B,
therefore  A ⊈ B.   [This is what needed to be shown.]

---

b. B  ⊆ A.
Suppose x is an arbitrarily chosen element of A.
By definition of A, there is an integer a, such that 6a+4.
Suppose y is a particular, but arbitrarily chosen element of B.
By definition of B, there is an integer b, such that 18b-2.
Suppose that y =1 then y= 18(1)-2 = 16.
If y, or 16 in this case is an element of B then it must be an element of A for B  ⊆ A.
If 6a+4=16 then,
6a=12
a=12/6
a=2.
Therefore, 16 is an element of both B and A, thus B  ⊆ A. [This is what needed to be shown.]

---

c.  B=C
Suppose y is an element of B and z is an element of C.  By definition of B, there is an integer b,
Such that 18b-2.  By definition of C, there is an integer c, such that 18c+16.  Suppose that b = 1
Then 18(1) -2 = 16.  If y, or in this case 16 ∈  B, then it must be an element of C for B  ⊆ C.
If 18c+ 16=16
c=0.
0 is an integer, thus y is an element of both B and C, thus B  ⊆ C.
For B=C, C must also be a subset of B.
We know that 0∈ C thus,
18b-2=0
b=1/9
B is not an integer, therefore C⊈B, thus B≠C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to show that $A \nsubseteq B$ it is enough to find a single element $x \in A$ which is not an element of $B$. You don't need to write "If x, or 10 in this case is an element of A, then it must be an element of B for A⊆B." Although it's fine to show $a \subseteq B$ results in a contradiction, it's simpler to just show $10 \in A$ but $10 \notin B$

In order to prove that one set is a subset of another, e.g., $B \subseteq A$, you show that any element of $B$ must be an element of $A$. You have successfully shown that 16 is an element of both sets, but not that every $b \in B$ is also in $A$.

In step c you're making an error when you write that "we know that $0 \in C$." $0$ is not in $C$, it is the integer in $\mathbb{Z}$ which we use as $c$ in the definition of $C$ to see that $16 \in C$ as $16 = 18*0 + 16$ and $0 \in \mathbb{Z}$

Try parts b and c again with this information. And remember that your sets, $A, B, C$ contain those elements $x, y, z$ which satisfy the predicates in their definitions, not the $a$,$b$,$c \in \mathbb{Z}$